# Unable to debug Word addin project, required version of Microsoft Office is not Installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ms-word, ms-office

My Colleague wanted me to work on a solutions on Team Foundation Server. When i connected i noticed that some of the projects would not load. From what we ascertained or theorized this could be due to conflicts with the version office, word or the various connected drivers or assemblies. So as a experiment i opened a new add in project in my vs 2012. It would build but i when tried to execute i got the above error. Ironically when i opened my word the add in was actually there but i cannot debug it? Office 2013 installed. I did install office 2007 assemblies, made no difference so i removed them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i created my project only the 2010 office templates were available but i only had the office 2013 installed. I needed to install the assemblies to allow the creation of add-in projects using 2013 office templates. I got the necessary download from Microsoft after direction on the VTSO forums.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach to automatically start the debugger when a certain process starts - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: when i navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentversion\, there is no directory called 'image file execution options' which is specified in the walk through. I am using the vs 2010 version of the walk through(the last version)?

Comment: Sorry my fault. Found the directory.Keep you posted.